# How to join two list of object based on its matching properties in Dart

Tags: dart

How to join two List of Object based on onjects properties and create a new list

For eg :

I have two list of classes

```
List<Product_name> name = [Product_name(1,'Product1'),Product_name(2,'Product2'),Product_name(3,'Product3')];
List<Prod_desc> desc =[Prod_desc(1,'Desc1'),Prod_desc(2,'Desc2')];
```

I need to create a new list of `Product` type when product id in `product_name` matches with `product_id` in `product_desc`

```
class Product_name{
  int product_id;
  String product_name;
  Product_name(this.product_id,this.product_name);
}

class Prod_desc{
  int product_id;
  String prod_desc;
  Prod_desc(this.product_id,this.prod_desc);
}

class Product{
  int product_id;
  String product_name;
  String prod_desc;
  Product(this.product_id,this.product_name,this.prod_desc);
}
```

Comment: Note that `Product_name` would idiomatically be `ProductName`. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-types-using-uppercamelcase

Answer (score 2):

Initialize an empty list

```dart
  List<Product> productList = [];
```

Iterate through each element in the arrays to find out matching items and add them to the list

```dart
  name.forEach((item) {
    desc.forEach((productDesc) {
      if (item.product_id == productDesc.product_id) {
        productList.add(Product(
          item.product_id,
          item.product_name,
          productDesc.prod_desc,
        ));
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your solution does not have `break` for inner iteration which may cause too many extra iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a `Map` to look up descriptions by ID.

```
var descriptionsById = {for (var d in desc) d.id: d.description};
var products = [
  for (var n in names) Product(n.id, n.name, descriptionsById[n.id]),
];
```